# What is the purpose of HTML evaluation in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, template-engine

I am currently learning Apps Script fundamentals. I've encounter a method:

```
evaluate()
```

e.g.

```
  const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("main");
  const html = htmlServ.evaluate(); //
```

Within [the reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template?hl=en#evaluate()) it says:

> It evaluates template and returns an HtmlOutput object.

**My question**: Does evaluate() has anything to do with security internally in Apps Script? Any relationship with HTML entities and its escaping? I want to clear this out.

Thanks.

Comment: @Cooper I assume this could be answer, unless someone would like to supplement your comment. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I removed it because I didn't think it completely answered your question.  I think it aids in security simply because you can load the load some content server side before final rendering but  beyond that I don't know.  There is something that may affect things that you asked about and I'll give you the same answer that another volunteer once gave me `caja sanitation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

evaluate() just injects data to your HTML templates. AFAIK it has nothing to do with the security.

The most common use case of this mechanism is when you have (nicely styled :)) HTML template that you want to have dynamic data. For example you have daily report that you want to display on a HTML page or send by email that has HTML body. But each day your Daily Total Revenue is different. You would do something like this:

```
<!-- Inside index.html file -->
<html>
  <div class=my-class">
    <p>Daily Total Revenue is: <?= dailyTotalRevenueVar ?>.</p>
  </div>
</html>

// Inside Code.gs file
const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
template.dailyTotalRevenueVar = 1000000; // Add a property to the template
const htmlOutput = template.evaluate(); // Replace var in HTML with actual value 1000000
Logger.log(htmlOutput.getContent()); // or return as a result in doGet()
```

You have many more options besides the simple value replacing, you can skip the entire HTML block if array has zero length, you can make a for loop to fill the select options...

Take a look at this page (toggle between .gs and .html view in code examples)
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

For more info about doGet and publishing GAS project as a web application visit this page:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Nice and neat. Thank you!